# About Node.js and asynchronous mongoDB calls

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

I'm new to node.js and have a non-asynchronous background, thus this makes me feel stupid trying to understand how to properly implement trivial sync tasks asynchronously.

For example, I have an object. I fetch it like this:

```
objManager.getObject(objId, function(error, object) {
  ...
})
```

objManager.getObject implements async call to mongoDB, fetches the object and passes it to the callback as second parameter. Then I need to return a new object, based on the previous one. But there is a flag in an object, which I need to either fetch from DB, or set a default value on. Here's logic I need:

```
objManager.getObject(objId, function(error, object) {
  var objToReturn = {
    first_prop: 1,
    second_prop: "2",
    third_prop: null
  };
  if (Globals.setThirdDefault) {
    // here i need to set it as default. 
    objToReturn.third_prop = defaultThird;
    // Then there is a lot of lines of code
    res.send();
  } else {
    // here I need to fetch the flag from mongoDB, 
    // and I need to repeat a "lot of lines" in the callback
    // as it is async, and if I won't do that, my res.send() 
    // will be called before callback returns
    objManager.getThirdValue(function (error, thirdValue) {
      objToReturn.third_prop = thirdValue;
      // again, there is a lot of lines of code
      res.send();
    })
  }
})
```

One way I see it could be managed is by using function for repeated code, but is this correct ? Should I create a lot of functions in order to manage several flags i need to fetch from db, like this ?

```
objManager.getObject(objId, function(error, object) {
  var objToReturn = {
    first_prop: 1,
    second_prop: "2",
    third_prop: null
  };

  var manageThird = function(thirdProp) {
    objToReturn.third_prop = thirdProp;
    // here will be my lines of code
  }

  if (Globals.setThirdDefault) {
    manageThird(defaultThird);
    res.send();
  } else {
    objManager.getThirdValue(function (error, thirdValue) {
      manageThird(thirdValue);
      res.send();
    })
  }
})
```

Will this work anyway ?

Comment: Seems ok. What you are struggling is not just async model, but more about Scopes.
So what the challenge and what is the question? As it does not look like you are asking anything, but want to know will it work or not. In order to find it out - just run it and see your self.

Comment: @MaksimsMihejevs Well, the real question is: do I think correctly ? Do I have to repeat my code in all this situations (or use functions), or there is another way I just don't see ?

Comment: @VitaliyLebedev The idea is absolutely correct. You might want to use some libraries though to help you with asynchronous calls, like [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async).

Comment: Or you might just create your own 'helper' functions that will make your life easier.

Comment: @MaksimsMihejevs, @ freakish thanks guys, this feeling that I'm missing something out just didn't want to go. You helped me :) Maksims, create an answer to this question, i'll accept it

Comment: @MaksimsMihejevs btw, if you have some material about creating these 'helper functions' for me to read, please share